# TransformToVisual returns incorrect result only for the first time

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to use the `TransformToVisual` method to get an Image element's absolute coordinates like this:

```
var transform = img.TransformToVisual( this ); // this is the current page
Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform( new Point(0, 0) );
```

For the first time I use it, this code returns an incorrect value (it is always 155,255). However, it always returns the correct coordinates afterwards.

This code runs in a Tap event handler, so the UI is already completely rendered when it is being executed. I tried calling `InvalidateMeasure` and `InvalidateArrange` (both on the Image element and on the page), but it did not help (I don't know if those calls have any connection whatsoever with `TransformToVisual`).

What could be the problem?

UPDATE: If I pin lock my phone and then unlock it, then the above issue does not happen.

UPDATE2: The position seems to be where the upper left hand corner of the image *would* be if it *was* at the center of the page. (The image's size is fixed 170x260. I get the coordinates 155,255. 2*155 + 170 = 480, 2*255 + 260 = 770 (okay the second one is not exactly 800, but it is suspicious anyway. The Application bar and the System tray are both hidden.))

UPDATE3: The problem occurs on the main page of my app. However, if I navigate to another page, then come back to the main page, it also works correctly.

Comment: Is 155,255 your design location?

Comment: No, don't think so. The Image element is in a ListBox (which has a toolkit WrapPanel as its ItemsPanelTemplate), so the position of the Image element is dynamic. I get 155,255 independently of which Image I try to position.

Comment: Does it work on your PC? Mine worked on my PC - I dont have a windows phone to hand to check it on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it does indeed work correctly in the emulator! (however I am still lost on the real device...)

Comment: So, we've narrowed it down to a quirk in the real device.. :( bleh.